# Patching on OData .Net Core 3.1 not reflecting the changes

Tags: c#, .net-core, odata

I'm trying to do PATCH operation using OData 7.4.0 on .Net Core 3.1. It seems like `CopyChangedValues()` method was not working properly on the version that I'm currently using. `GET` operation really works on my end. It's working on the older version but I've already migrated to 3.1.

[Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBQ5G.png)

Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Did the Model change?  There is a similar issue from earlier today : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62281221/invalid-cast-exception-xunit-deserialization-error/62281222#comment110192647_62281222

Comment: @jdweng no the model doesn't change. This is really weird.

Comment: As I said in the link : Microsoft doesn't care about Forward/Backward compatibility.

Comment: There are two reasons for issues like this 1) There is something wrong with the mapping  with uses the DBMX file 2)  The driver in the connection string.  Some drives/databases need to be updated when version change.

Comment: Hi @jdweng actually I directly connected to database. I'm not using DBMX file.

Comment: DBMX is the mapping file. You cannot directly connect, there is always a connection string with driver.  The connection string may be buried in the configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```cs
delta.Patch(entity);
```

Comment: Hi! @crgolden, what version are you currently using?

Comment: I use Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Versioning.ApiExplorer v4.1.1.